# Java - possible lossy conversion from byte to char

Tags: java

This surprised me:

```
char c = 'M';
byte b = -1;
c = b; //incompatible types
```

Why is this a possibly lossy conversion? A byte is 8 bits and size of a char in Java is always 16 bits, so I would expect this to be promotion.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) has a table with all the primitive types. (And their JNI mappings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` is unsigned (has a range of 0 to 2^16 - 1), so `-1` is not within its range.

`byte`, on the other hand, is signed, and has a range of -128 to 127. Therefore, even though a b `byte` is represented by half the bits of a `char`, not all the possible `byte` values are also `char` values.

BTW, `char` is the only unsigned type is Java, so for other integral types (`int`,`long`) this assignment would work.

Comment: It is discouraged to answer duplicate questions as per the FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled. One should search for appropriate duplicates and vote to close instead.

Comment: @Brikowski Oh I was not addressing you, posting duplicate questions is not a problem at all, on the contrary!